# What is the difference between polynomial and multinomial regressions in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, polynomials

I'm currently trying to master regression and I've come across people using the words polynomial and multinomial quite interchangeably, yet I've also heard people say multinomial regression is a part of polynomial regression. I'm obviously confused.

I know a polynomial function is goes something like this: `f(x)=ax^2+bx+c` but to my knowledge that is also a multinomial function.

So do poly and multi mean the same thing? Or is there an actual difference?

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote them and accept the best one. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multinomials are polynomials that contain more than one term. Monomials are a type of polynomial but they are not a type of multinomial.

Comment: So then a monomial is also linear?

Comment: No, x^2 is a monomial because it contains only one term